# How to interpret the following operations in R programming language?

Tags: r, data-science

Here is what to be coded in R:

sum_{n=1}^{10}\left(\frac{2^{n}}{n^2} + \frac{n^{4}}{4^{n}}\right)

Comment: `n = 1:10; sum( 2^n/n^2 + n^4/4^n )`

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr` I'd say something like:

`sum(map_dbl(1:10, fun(x) 2^x/^2+x^4/4^x)`